# A 70 foot pole stands pulled and anchored to three equally spaced points in the plane. How many feet apart are any two of those anchor points?

Tags: geometry

A $70\text{ ft}$ pole stands vertically in a horizontal plane supported by three $490 \text{ ft}$  wires, all attached to the top of the pole. Pulled and anchored to three equally spaced points in the plane.

How many feet apart are any two of those anchor points?
Answer: $149.61$

Comment: I don't think the answer $149.61$ is correct.

Comment: Your approach should be right.Ans is just a number.by the way this ans was  given in the book

Comment: It is true, but what I said was just to inform you and others not to be distracted by the wrong answer.

Comment: @frin  please include a sketch.

Answer (score 1):

We need to use the Pythagorean theorem to find the distance from the foot of the pole to the anchor point and then use the cosine rule to find the distance between each anchor point.
[image]

Answer (score 0):

If I understand your question correctly:
with pythagoras you could calculate the distance from the anchor points to the bottom of the pole. The distance of the three points to the pole is the same, so they are on a circle. 
Divide 360 by 3 and you get the corner between all anchor points.
This newly created triangle has to sides of the same length (radius circle), so the relation of the 3 sides of the triangle is 1:1:sqrt(2).
Now you should be able to calculate the distance between two anchor points

Answer (score 0):

The distance from the base of the pole to each of the anchor points is $\sqrt{490^2-70^2}\approx 484.97$. The picture is of three points equally spaced on the circumference of a circle whose radius is about $484.97$ feet.

The distance, however, is not the arc length. It is the largest side of a 30-30-120 isosceles triangle whose smaller sides are $484.97$ feet. To get that, we multiply by $\sqrt{3}$ to get $484.97\sqrt{3}= 839.94$ feet.

Comment: in the last part how to get this √ 3 that i can not understand @John Douma

Comment: c sqr= a sqr+b sqr+2abcosc this should be use

Comment: @frin That should be $-2ab\cos{\theta}$. Use the law of cosines with $a = b = r$ and $\theta = 120^{\circ}$.